# Перебор вариаций

Tags: python, перебор

Чтобы было понятнее разобью на ключевые параметры:

1. Имеется несколько групп, каждая группа имеет свои подгруппы, которые в свою очередь тоже делятся на подгруппы.
2. Требуется сделать перебор этих вариаций.
3. Сложность заключается в том, что обмен происходит между клиентом и сервером по порциям.

Мои мысли по этому поводу: сделать это через словарь, и потом по ключам обращаться к параметрам и записывать строки, которые в свою очередь запоминать и передавать клиенту, который будет их возвращать, но побаиваюсь того, что ключи словаря могут сбиться и тогда это все коту под хвост...

Может, у кого-то были подобные случаи - как из них выходили?

Для визуализации покажу примерную картинку:
[image: Пример перебора]

Comment: Не очень понятно, что конкретно требуется, но itertools.product выдаст все сочетания, содержащие  по элементу из каждой группы

Comment: Пачка может быть случайным размером, например по 10 штук, а комбинаций всего, например 123, тогда пользователь узнает все комбинации только после 13 отправок. Если было бы за 1 раз то тут можно просто через for все комбинации перебрать...

Comment: @MBo, ок попробую через него(**itertools.product**). использованные комбинации буду выкидывать тогда

Comment: @MBo, не подскажите, как сделать выбор из имеющегося перебора не по порядку, а чтобы каждое выбранное значение отличалось от предыдущего (без повтора имеющегося элемента из прошлой комбинации)